# Flutter - Fast swipe detection

Tags: flutter, swipe

I am building an application with swipeable cards in a deck.

Swiping works perfectly fine at any speed so long as I am swiping sort of at least 50% of the distance of the screen.

People don't tend to do this however, it is a better user experience to just swipe a very short distance quickly left or right and have the application detect the intent and complete the scroll action.

My code is as follows:

```
void _onHorizontalDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    startDrag = details.globalPosition;
    startDragPercentScroll = scrollPercent;
  }

  void _onHorizontalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    final currentDrag = details.globalPosition;
    final dragDistance = currentDrag.dx - startDrag.dx;
    final singleCardDragPercent = dragDistance / context.size.width;

    setState(() {
      scrollPercent = (startDragPercentScroll + (-singleCardDragPercent / widget.cards.length)).clamp(0.0, 1.0 - (1 / widget.cards.length));
    });
  }

  void _onHorizontalDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    finishScrollStart = scrollPercent;
    finishScrollEnd = (scrollPercent * widget.cards.length).round() / widget.cards.length;
    finishScrollController.forward(from: 0.0);

    setState(() {
      startDrag = null;
      startDragPercentScroll = null;
    });
  }
```

I am certain there is just something wrong with my math there somewhere that is preventing short, quick swipes from working.

What happens instead is the card moves a short distance and then snaps back to the same card.

Comment: you are sayin that `_onHorizontalDragEnd` is not called if you do a "short drag"?

Comment: It seems to, but I think the math detects if the current card has slid over 50% of the screen width, to make it snap the rest of the way.   But it also detects if it is under 50% of the distance and snaps back.   Want to be able to flick through the cards quickly and I think my math must be wrong.

Comment: @Bisclavret I'm at the same situation myself now, were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, @Yoni.   I was not able to find a solution to this and my app still scrolls sluggishly.